# interior surface of furnaces

Tags: radiation

For industrial furnaces, in order to improve radiation heat transfer and save energy, some people say applying a high emissivity coating on to the interior surface of a furnace will do, while some people say applying a high reflectivity coating will do. we all know that at given wavelength and for an opaque object surface, emissivity + reflectivity =1, anyone can explain to me please?

With best regards

Sean

Answer (score 1):

The First Law requires that at any given wavelength emissivity must exactly equal absorptivity.  If you heat a cavity with an external intense optical heat source, a mirror surface will distribute the energy (as will a diffusive rough white surface) without hot spots.  However, if the cavity is thermally emissive (heating coils or bars in or behind the surface), you want an absolutely black surface in the IR that is porous on the order of your lambda(max) for the temperature desired.

Rule of thumb,a furnace firing black objects treats them as being transparent to heat.  A furnace firing white objects (e.g., bisque firing) requires care in placement for even temperatures.

A third case is a home kiln in a microwave oven( e.g., Fuseworks) , typically lined with silicon carbide, magnetite, graphite.  At low temps SiC is a good susceptor and heats rapidly.  Toward orange heat (~900 C) SiC becomes microwave transparent and so plateaus in temp.  Use a cheap microwave oven.

Comment: Keep in mind the "gotcha"  $\epsilon = \alpha$ but the amount absorbed depends on the incident light flux while the amount emitted depends on the body's temperature (not how much flux it absorbed)

Comment: Thank you Uncle Al. Very informative answer. I am looking at  heating a chamber with external heating source (such as flame into a chamber fired from combustion burners.....). It seems straightforward that a interior mirror surface of a chamber will reflect thermal radiation to the working zone, however, the high emissivity coating can rapidly absorb heat then re-radiate back. and i did some search on the internet, all i found is that High emissivity coatings are applied in the interior surface of furnaces for efficiency improvement (google "high emissivity coating", i get a lot results....)

Comment: Meanwhile, in production, the internal surface of a combustion chamber is also subject to other forms of thermal input (conduction, convection and molecular kinetic energy), these heat transfer also makes interior surface get hot and emit energy to the working zone of the chamber.